# Rails and databases - Store old data in a separate table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, optimization

Okay, so I'm putting together a book store with Ruby on Rails. Books are fast moving and varied, so at any point of time there are a small number in the store. Books that have been ordered and shipped must be stored, mainly for the purpose of records.

Hence, I have a situation where a small section of data from a table is going to be very frequently accessed. A much much larger section of it will very rarely accessed at all. My plan is to move books that have been ordered and shipped to a separate table, so that the table of current books is small and very quick to access.

Does this approach make sense? Is there a better way of achieving this?

If I am to use this approach, is there a way of sharing a model between tables in Rails?

Comment: what is the total amount of books?  i'd say if it is like 100,000 or so, no way will it be worth another table...

Comment: The number will actually be far less than that =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with [Randy's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318749/randy) comment about considering the number of books in the database, and whether or not it's really worth it. Only after you try it, and come back with real performance numbers to consider should you consider optimizing in this way, I believe.

On the other hand, there's plenty of precedent for having the idea of an "archive" table. From a design standpoint, this is totally fine. It's a question of the tradeoff between complexity and performance. But again, only after you try it and see whether or not the performance is acceptable, will you have a solid reason to choose one approach over another.